# WKWebView load fails randomly with NSURLErrorDomain Code -1200

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView created in IB that I load with an external url from Squarespace in viewWillAppear. As the page I'm loading is static I use cachePolicy .returnCacheDataElseLoad so I don't have to reload the page every time.

Usually it's working good. The page is loaded and the didFinish navigation delegate method is called. Now I started seeing some strange behavior, instead of getting the didFinish I get didFailProvisionalNavigation with SSL Error: NSURLErrorSecureConnectionFailed (-1200).

**This behavior happens:**

- iOS 13.2.3
- Only sometimes, the next time the same URL is working. Often deleting the app and reinstalling will help (removing the cache and reloading the page).
- When on a mobile data connection (never when on WIFI)
- Having a stable data connection (other pages in Safari are loading fine)
- Only on 2 out of 8 test devices (With iPhone 11 Pro Max and iPhone X Max so far)

I don't think there are any issues with the SSL certificates because Squarespace handles that.

Any idea what can be wrong here? Otherwise what can I do to investigate more? I'm stuck!

**The code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://www.subdomain.domain.com/article/en") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 30.0)
            webView.navigationDelegate = self
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) { }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) { }
}
```

Comment: Try to use it with another page where it works for sure -> e.g. `https://www.google.com/`. `NSURLErrorSecureConnectionFailed` typically fires for SSL Errors. An also try to view that website in the Safari or Chrome-App -> do you get any Errors. Can also suggest to Remote-Debug it (https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/)

Comment: In Safari it's working perfect. Loading other pages works fine. Also loading this page can work randomly the next time I try.

Comment: You can also try to clear the Cookies during the tests (Settings-> Safari) and check if something changes. However, this looks like an issue caused by the site. Just to narrow the issue and to find out if it's `WKWebView` or the Website -> you could also try to use the (deprecated) `UIWebView`. Perhaps also try to enable `Allow Arbitrary Loads` in you `*.plist-file` and check if something changes.

Comment: @seeya thank you! It seems you are right, the page is not working in Safari and Chrome either. But just switching WIFI on and off again makes it work. This is so random. Have you seen anything like this?

Comment: did you found what was the issue? Solved it?